# Vertical Tangent line with Implicit Differentiation

Tags: implicit-differentiation

The original equation is $$x^2-2xy+y^3= 4$$ and I hope the derivative to be $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2(x-y)}{2x-3y^2}$$

I know the vertical tangent is when the denominator is $0$, but I am having trouble determining the vertical tangent.

Comment: A vertical tangent appears if the denominator is zero AND the numerator is not...

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange

Answer (score 2):

The equation
$$\bigl(f(x,y):=\bigr)\qquad x^2-2xy+y^3=4$$
defines a set $S$  in the $(x,y)$-plane. This set is, generally speaking, a curve, maybe with singularities. You want to know the points of $S$ where the tangent to $S$ is vertical. Now $S$ can be considered as a level line of the function $f$. Level lines are at each of their points orthogonal to $\nabla f$ at this point. It follows that at the points $p\in S$ where the tangent to $S$ is vertical the gradient $\nabla f(p)$ has to be horizontal, which means that $f_y(x,y)=0$ at such points. Therefore these $p=(x,y)$ will come to the fore by solving the system
$$x^2-2xy+y^3=4, \quad -2x+3y^2=0\ .$$
Maybe this system has several solutions $p_k=(x_k,y_k)$. The equation of the tangent to $S$ at $p_k$ is then given by $x=x_k$.